# Double click "Laser On" Double click "Laser Off" - Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-uno

Thank you all for your time.
I Have my code that when I keep holding the button the laser turn on "HIGH"
when I release my finger from the button the laser turns off "LOW"

But I want when I double click the laser turn on and when I double click again the laser turn off.

Thank you and sorry for my bad English.

````
const int btn = 6;// The push button
int previousButtonStateLAZER = HIGH;   // for btn6

void setup(){
  pinMode(btn, INPUT);
  pinMode (laserPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  int buttonStateLAZER = digitalRead(btn);

  // if the button state has changed,
  if (buttonStateLAZER != previousButtonStateLAZER){
    if( buttonStateLAZER == HIGH ) {
      digitalWrite (laserPin, HIGH);
    }else{
      digitalWrite (laserPin, LOW);
    }
  }
  previousButtonStateLAZER = buttonStateLAZER;
}```
````

Comment: 1. Define what a double click is. 2. Draw (on paper) a state machine that shows how to transition between all states. 3. Translate this state machine to code only AFTER you have it drawn out.

Comment: Tried different solutions but still nothing works fine.

Comment: Define a double click. You're going to need to use the Arduino's timer functionality. Are two clicks 1 hour apart from each other a double click?

Comment: Because I'm new at Arduino world so I need to find useful links dor buttons and states and so on. BTW Thank you so much

Comment: Do you know what a state machine is?

Comment: Well, I'm not looking to replace your engineering lectures, but the wikipedia article is a good place to start. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the last two times that a click was detected and then test to see if they occurred close enough together. Try this code out (edited from what you posted):

```
const int btn = 6;// The push button
int previousButtonStateLAZER = LOW;   // for btn6

static long releaseTimes[2];
static int releaseIndex = 1;

static int laserStates[2];
static int laserIndex = 0;

void setup(){
  pinMode(btn, INPUT);
  pinMode (laserPin, OUTPUT);

  releaseTimes[0] = 0;
  releaseTimes[1] = 0;

  laserStates[0] = LOW;
  laserStates[1] = HIGH;
}

void loop(){
  int buttonStateLAZER = digitalRead(btn);

  // if the button state has changed,
  if (buttonStateLAZER != previousButtonStateLAZER){
      previousButtonStateLAZER = buttonStateLAZER;

      if (buttonStateLAZER == HIGH) {
          return;
      }

      releaseIndex = 1 - releaseIndex;
      releaseTimes[releaseIndex] = millis();

      if (abs(releaseTimes[0] - releaseTimes[1]) < 800) {
          releaseTimes[0] = 0;
          releaseTimes[1] = 0;
          laserIndex = 1 - laserIndex;
          digitalWrite(laserPin, laserStates[laserIndex]);
      }
  }

}
```